# Font Stack which includes Museo is not working at all in FireFox and Opera

Tags: firefox, opera, embedded-fonts

I am using three different fonts. Here is my @fontface

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Mikadan-Regular'; 
src: url('../fonts/mikadan/eot/style_134713.eot');
src: url('../fonts/mikadan/eot/style_134713.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/mikadan/woff/style_134713.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/mikadan/ttf/style_134713.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/mikadan/svg/style_134713.svg#Mikadan-Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'MuseoSans500';
src: url('../fonts/museosans_500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/museosans_500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/museosans_500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/museosans_500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/museosans_500/MuseoSans_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSans500') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'MuseoSlab500';
src: url('../fonts/museoslab_500/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/museoslab_500/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/museoslab_500/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/museoslab_500/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/museoslab_500/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSlab500') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

The first and the third work fine.

The second one is specified for the body tag as:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
font: 16px/1.625 MuseoSans500 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
_font-size: 1em;
color: #333;
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari

However, in Opera 11.50 and Firefox 4.0.1, bad news; the entire font stack does not work, and the font is rendered as plain old serif (yuck!)

I think the problem is with Museo,as when I take Museo out of the font stack it renders correctly.

I'm using these browsers on Windows 7.

Comment: Does it still break when adding a comma after MuseoSans500 in the second CSS bit?

Comment: No, I'm so embarrassed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma.

```
font: 16px/1.625 MuseoSans500 "Lucida Grande"
font: 16px/1.625 MuseoSans500, "Lucida Grande"
                            ^^^ add this comma
```

Comment: Thank you. How embarrassing - I've spent ages trying to sort this and it was staring me in the face all along! Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are missing that comma now, based on what you said, you were having problems with the MuseoSans500 font for body text. When you removed it you were fine. I think the comma is missing now that you are showing us your code.

I would try setting font-family to one choice at a time and see what happens. I would also separate the font-size and line-height just in case thereby isolating the problem, like so:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: MuseoSans500; /* start with this one by itself */
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.625;
  color: #333;
}
```